# My MergeSort not reading right side

Tags: java, sorting, recursion, mergesort

My MergeSort code is not reading the right side.
I think the problem must be at the recursion of MergeSort. If I put the right part : MergeSort(S,(q+1),last); before the other recursion it is not reading the left side. Here is my code:

```
first = 0;
last = S.length;
// START - MergeSort

public static int[] MergeSort(int[] S,int first,int last){
    if(first<last){
        int q = (first+last)/2;
        MergeSort(S,first,q);
        MergeSort(S,(q+1),last);
        Merge(S,first,q,(q+1),last);
    }
    return S;
}

public static void Merge(int[] S,int first1,int last1,int first2,int last2){

    int N = last1 - first1 + 1;
    int M = last2 - first2 + 1;
    int Total = N+M-1;

    int[] A = new int[N];
    int[] B = new int[M];
    int[] C = new int[Total];

    int posA=0;
    int posB=0;
    int posC=0;

    for(int i=first1; i<N; i++){
        A[i] = S[i];
    }

    for(int i=first2; i<M; i++){
        B[i] = S[i];
    }

    while(posA<N && posB<M){
            if(A[posA]<B[posB]){
                C[posC]=A[posA];
                posA++;
                posC++;
            }
            else{
                C[posC]=B[posB];
                posB++;
                posC++;
            }

    }

    // IF ANYTHING LEFT!
    if(posA==N && posB<M){
        for(int i=posC;i<Total;i++){
            C[i]=B[posB];
            posB++;
        }
    }
    if(posB==M && posA<N){
        for(int i=posC;i<Total;i++){
            C[i]=A[posA];
            posA++;
        }
    }
    // DONE!
```

Comment: Please use [Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconventions-135099.html#367) for all your code. Methods should be in `camelCase`. Not adhering to these conventions makes it harder for us to read your code (and also messes up the syntax highlighting).

Comment: http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: What is your expected output? Because I just ran the example with outputs and it's definitely running the second `MergeSort()` in the method?

Comment: I give it an array for example ( 3,2,5,6,1) and it compares 3 with 0. Then 3,2 with 0. and for the second part (5,6,1) everything is 0. It compares 0 with 0 then 0 with 0... EDITED! Finally it outputs 0,0,1,5,6 So one part is gone.

Comment: Maybe my answer to this question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21771119/java-merge-sorting-algorithm-error-not-sorting/21771714#comment32937797_21771714), can help you debug your code

Comment: I don't believe this is doing anything at all. You are copying all the values to the C array, and are never copying it back to S array. You are just returning the array you called with without doing anything to it.

Answer (score 0):

You should set `q = first + (last - first)/2;`

Also, you initialize `last = S.length` You should initialize it to `last = S.length - 1`

You can find a very good implementation here in [The Vogella Tutorials](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaAlgorithmsMergesort/article.html)

Comment: That's not going to do it surely? `first` == 0, so removing it from p still isn't going to sort their issue. The recursion will still be an infinite loop.

Comment: Tried. Didn't helped. Problem still remains.

Comment: @RudiKershaw An `if` statement is not a loop. It will only be entered so long as `first` is less than `last`. When it is entered, it will make a recursive call to the function. Eventually `first` will equal `last` and the `if` statement will not be entered effectively terminating the recursion for that initial call.

Comment: @BrianVanover Right. All MergeSort I saw are the same. My MergeSort has 3 variables and Merge 5. So it's a bit different the way its done.

Comment: @STUDENT_LIFE try the second correction that I just provided.

Comment: I realize I forgot about the truncating from being cast back down to an int. You would never reach 0 with floating points, but with ints that isn't a problem.